# How do I extract specific data from txt file using fgets?

Tags: c, file, parsing, fgets

I have a text document which has data stored in the following format:

```
NUNMBER OF CLIENTS  6
//---------------------
Client ID: 1
Name John Barnes
Gender MALE 
Occupation EMPLOYED
//---------------------
Client ID: 2
Name Sarah Barnes
Gender FEMALE 
Occupation EMPLOYED
//---------------------
Client ID: 3
Name Carol Hughes
Gender FEMALE 
Occupation EMPLOYED
//---------------------
```

How do I (within C) extract specific data i.e if the user just wants to see the names of all the females or the names of all those that are unemployed? I have written code for user input to what they are searching for but need to extract the data from the txt file. preferably using fgets command.

Many Thanks

Comment: I'd imagine there's a `struct client { int id; char name[30]; int gender; int occupation; };` somewhere --- show your code!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what exactly you need help with; to get started, and assuming all your entries have those same 4 fields, you could declare a `struct` to represent them like this:

```c
enum gender {male, female /* and more, if you want*/};
struct entry {
   int client_id;
   char *name;
   enum gender gender;
   char *occupation;
};
```

and then read the file line by line, switching to a new entry struct whenever you reach a line like `//------`

Does that help? :D

Comment: Thank you - I am new to C programming and struggling slightly with an assignment.